# testing a virtual environment (virtualenv)

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip

I'm not sure if it makes sense but I would like to be able to test my virtual environments to see if everything a particular project needs is indeed installed from requirements files and none of the requirements / dependencies are missing.
How could I do it?

Comment: Just run `pip install -r requirements.txt`?

Comment: That's what comes to my mind too. But for whatever reason pip could fail, even for human reasons if someone messes with the requirements. I would like to rely on another tool to independently check the dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [yolk](https://github.com/cakebread/yolk) to spot out-of-date dependencies:

```
$ yolk --show-updates
 Paste 1.7.2 (1.7.5.1)
 PasteDeploy 1.3.3 (1.5.0)
 PasteScript 1.7.3 (1.7.5)
 coverage 3.4 (3.6)
…
```

To install missing ones, the usual way is to have a `requirements.txt` for `pip install -r`. If you mean how to initially build one of those, then running e.g. `pylint` on your project will uncover unsatisfied imports.

Comment: checking unsatisfied imports with pylint seems to be a good idea in this case.